# Best way to deploy Azure Webjobs on an Azure AppServicePlan

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Supposing I have 1 Azure AppService Plan, is it better to deploy 
•   2 Web Jobs on a Single App Service (which is tied to the above 1 APSP) or 
•   2 Web jobs to 2 different App Services (which are both tied to the above 1 APSP).

I understand that creating an Azure AppService creates a W3Wp.exe instance on the PaaS VM (which is nothing but the Azure AppServicePlan). So, if I have 2 App Services on a single APSP, there would be 2 W3wp.exe instances created. Want to know the best and ideal way to deploy multiple webjobs on Azure.

Comment: The only decent answer here should be: it depends. It depends on what you need, it depends on how heavy the webjobs will be, it depends on so may things... As is, this question is bound to get primarily opinion based answers.

Comment: I am actually not asking what Tier I have to have the APSP on - just want the best way to deploy WebJobs given that App Services create an instance of W3Wp.exe.

Comment: The answer stays the same... Is it best to have _one_ process on only _one_ App Service Plan? Or is it best to join tasks inside one App Service Plan? And is it really the best solution, or do you _think_ it is? There is no _best_, there might be a _prefered_ at most. And even then it depends on multiple things.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to rickvdbosch

It dependents.

In 2 WebJobs running on a single app service, if one webjob deployed with appsettings / connection strings, it will lead to restart of other webjob.

Also, development/devops team need to manage both webjob configurations together on a single app service without any conflicts.

In case of 2 webjobs running in different app service
The above issues can be overcome in this approach.
If the AppService is intended to use only for WebJobs and not for website/webapplication/api, then AppService can be stopped / turned off. This will stop the w3wp process running on the app service plan, but the webjob will continue to run until it is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

From a cost optimization point of view deploying to single app service plan is good. Pricing is based on the size and number of instances you run. It also depends like always both web jobs will be performing heavy tasks or it may be running in separate interval like after one web job finished other job run. This was one web job still can utilize maximum resources.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/app-service/windows/